# Use Foursquare for venue locations but not Photos

Tags: android, ios, foursquare

I am making an app (iOS and Android) which will show selected venues on Campus and near campus, i.e. only places where food costs less than $10 (I have the name of the shops in CSV file).

Here is my plan:

Get venue ID for all those shops and store them in the app. The app will get the JSON feed for all the Venues nearby and my app will filter out the venues which does not have a Venue ID in the local database.

In future versions of the app i want to add all the features of Foursquare (Check In, Tips and badges) but i DO NOT want to use their venue Photos. I only want to show photos added by the user of my App.

What options do I have to filter out the photos of people who are not using my app?

Do I have to use something like parse.com to store my users photo on the cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upload photos to Foursquare, get the Photo Url from the response. Store that to your database and tied to the Foursquare Venue Id.

When you display a Foursquare venue, grab the photos from your database by filtering with the Foursquare Venue Id.

If you are using Parse or your own database, you should be store with these columns: FoursquareVenueId, PhotoUrl.